# How to convert XML file to WSDL file?

Tags: xml, wsdl, converters

I have an XML file in my hand. I want to convert this file into a WSDL format. I need help with how to do it

Comment: can you post the xml? Maybe only a small part of it?

Comment: 12 thousand lines :)

Comment: Can you at least describe it? What is the content of your file?

Comment: I have an e-declaration data. I need to transfer this Web service. I need the WSDL file for this too